# Shell script to pull a number

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script that pulls the number of online players, but I need a little help.

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null \
    | grep PlayerCount \
    | head -1l \
    | sed 's/^[^>]*>//' \
    | sed "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%r %b %d %Y')/"
```

It outputs the following:

```
<p class="top"><span>69,215</span> people 06:31:37 PM Nov 22 2011
```

What I would like it to say is this:

```
69,215 people 06:31:37 PM Nov 22 2011
```

Can any of you help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of many different ways to do this.  Used `cut` and `sed` (`cut -d">" -f 3,4 | sed 's/<\/span>//'`):

```
[ 15:40 jon@hozbox.com ~ ]$ echo "<p class="top"><span>69,215</span> people 06:31:37 PM Nov 22 2011" | cut -d">" -f 3,4 | sed 's/<\/span>//'
69,215 people 06:31:37 PM Nov 22 2011



#!/usr/bin/bash
wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null \
    | grep PlayerCount \
    | head -1l \
    | sed 's/^[^>]*>//' \
    | sed "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%r %b %d %Y')/" \
    | cut -d">" -f 3,4 \
    | sed 's/<\/span>//'
```

Comment: Hmm so do I just add:      cut -d">" -f 3,4 | sed 's/<\/span>//'      to the next line at the end?

Comment: I'm really stupid lol. Can you paste what my whole script should look like? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Yea, just add a "|" and then put my text after it.

Comment: Added the whole script to the answer for ya.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output to:

```
sed 's%<p class="top"><span>\(.*\)</span>%\1%'
```

Or combine the two separate `sed` scripts you already have with this one, giving you:

```
sed -e 's/^[^>]*>//' \
    -e "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%r %b %d %Y')/" \
    -e 's%<p class="top"><span>\(.*\)</span>%\1%'
```

In fact, the `grep` and `head` commands are also superfluous; you could do the lot with a single `sed` command.  Note that putting the `|` on the end of the line means you don't need a backslash.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
wget --output-document=- http://runescape.com/title.ws 2>/dev/null |
    sed -e '/PlayerCount/!{d;n}' \
        -e 's/^[^>]*>//' \
        -e "s/currently.*$/$(date '+%r %b %d %Y')/" \
        -e 's%<p class="top"><span>\(.*\)</span>%\1%' \
        -e 'q'
```

The `/PlayerCount/!n` means skip to the next input line unless the input matches 'PlayerCount'.  The next three lines do what they always did.  The last line implements `head -1l` by printing (implicitly) and quitting.

(*As a matter of idle interest, the `wget` command produces some 790 lines of data if it runs to completion.  I get a '`cannot write to "-" (Broken pipe)`' error if I don't redirect standard error to `/dev/null` (plus some progress reporting that isn't wanted).  There are probably options to handle that; it also appears there's only one line with 'PlayerCount' so you could omit the '`-e q`' command.*)

Comment: So the 2nd bunch you listed there, do I replace all my sed scripts with what you listed?

Comment: Thanks for posting more! I'm looking over it.

Comment: After I try running that nothing is outputted :s

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after is code that removes any tags.  Your `sed 's/^[^>]*>//'` only replaces the up to the first `>`.

You may want to consider `sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'` instead.